# why use an integer algorithm for fft

Tags: integer, fft

I'm working on a simple signal processing project where I apply a fft on an input signal, find a peak within a frequency range, filter around that peak frequency, and plot the signal in the resulting pass band. I've done this in python, and now I've been asked to use an integer algorithm in C.

I'm looking for some clarification on why an integer algorithm would, in general, ever be required or desired. I can suppose that performance and memory overhead would be greatly improved, but any guidance on the details of why would be great. Also, what are some hardware application where this would actually matter? Arduino, mobile?

Any tips or pointers to information are appreciated.

Comment: Isn't this a question you should be posing to whoever asked you to do this?

Comment: I'm looking for general responses, not something tailored to a particular application. So, in general, what are the benefits of using an integer algorithm in fft.

Comment: Well that's quite a broad remit!  But assuming that "integer algorithm" means simply an FFT that performs only integer operations, then the answer is basically it's useful anywhere where the cost of floating-point operations is prohibitive, e.g. a platform with no FPU (or equivalent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Designing an Integer-only algorithm is desirable, mostly for performance, in practically any hardware application today.
Traditionally, any general purpose digital processor would contain dedicated circuitry to perform Integer operations. Now imagine, if you had to do any single floating point mathematical operation on paper (assuming the numbers are not whole), you would ultimately use some technique that breaks down the operation to multiple Integer operations. Here's a simplistic example:

1.1 * 2.0 = 
(1 * 2) + (0.1 * 2) = 
(1 * 2) + (1 * 2) * 0.1 = 
(1 * 2) + (1 * 2) / 10

So here a single floating-point multiplication turned into 2 Integer multiplications, a division and an addition. You can imagine now that any compiler would do this conversion for you so the Integer processing circuitry can do the work, and the total amount of CPU instructions increases by A LOT every time this is done.

Modern processors will have dedicated floating point circuitry but even then this circuitry is considerably more complex and takes more time to complete instructions when compared to Integer processing circuitry.

Comment: That's quite a poor analogy of how floating-point arithmetic is carried out (in fact, it's closer in spirit to simple long multiplication).  Multiplication of numbers in scientific notation would be a much better analogy.

Comment: Hence 'simplistic', Mr. Charlesworth. I was demonstrating how one might do this with pen and paper in order to appeal to people less familiar with how processors actually work. If you feel you have more to add - simply add it.

Answer (score 1):

Processors with fewer transistors (such within the AVR chips in Arduinos) don't have floating point arithmetic hardware, and software emulation of floating point arithmetic is magnitudes slower and much less power efficient.  A few decades ago when many DSP textbooks were written, such processors were far more common (even for cabinet-sized minicomputers).  Today, smaller FPGAs and IoT processors meant to operate from a single coin cell, or even smaller battery (hearing aids, etc.), may still have such active transistor count limitations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking into doing integer FFT because I had to promote the output of my RTL2832 dongle from 8 bit unsigneds to floats just so I could do FFT.  It seemed a little silly and it samples 2 million times per second.

But other than that I think floating point processors are more like calculators than they are like computers.  They possibly use BCD instead of binary inside, they work with base 10 numbers (like we do) rather than base 2 or 16.